# JQuery UI Datetimepicker is not working on Chrome

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, datepicker

my JQuery ui datetimepicker are not working on Google Chrome(working fine on IE ,Firefox...),
i have tried every solution and this is my final code

```
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css")

@Styles.Render("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajaxa/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/base/jquery-ui.css")
@Styles.Render("~/css/style.css")

@Scripts.Render("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js")

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js")


<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


  <script>
    $().ready(function () {
        // This will make every element with the class "date-picker" into a DatePicker element
        $('.date-picker').datetimepicker({ maxDate: '+0', changeYear: true, yearRange: "-70:+0" });
    });
</script>
```

and the view:

```
  @Html.TextBox("ToDate", "to date", new { @class = "form-control date-picker" })
```

any idea ?

Comment: can you try replacing $() with $(document)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem, it's weird but i had an commented code in my view file,  when i deleted them the problem was solved.